# Wi-Fi + Proxy Configuration from Glassware

Tags: android, proxy, google-glass

I need to connect my Glasses to a network with Wi-Fi (protected by PEAP) and accessing internet through a proxy.

I built, thanks to [jzplusplus](https://github.com/jzplusplus/GlassWifiConnect), a glassware to set up the Wi-Fi with PEAP security.
Now I'm trying to route **the whole system** to the proxy, as I would do with the "Advanced Options" in a regular Android device. But I can't manage to find any solutions.

I tried to access the `System.Globals` object, but couldn't because I need `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission, which is not available.

I tried to implement [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486441/how-can-i-set-proxysettings-and-proxyproperties-on-android-wi-fi-connection-usin) which unfortunately has *no effect* on the device.

I end up being connected to the Wi-Fi, but can't access any data.

**How can I programmatically (or even manually, that would be acceptable) set up a proxy on my Google Glasses?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be impossible to do on the whole system, as the API that can do such thing requires a special permission and key.

So well, the proxy has to be managed per application.