# How to Set wifi proxy Hostname, port and bypass programmatically in Android 5.0 and above

Tags: java, android, proxy, wifi

I want to set wifi proxy hostname, port and bypass programmatically. i follow this link **->[How can I set ProxySettings and ProxyProperties on Android Wi-Fi connection using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486441/how-can-i-set-proxysettings-and-proxyproperties-on-android-wi-fi-connection-usin)**. but that code is not working on Android 5.0.2. Is there any other way to set those settings?

Comment: https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy i think this library will help you.. I dont tested it

Comment: There is a answer related to Android 5 in the question you linked.

Comment: @Jackson Chengalai : this liberary is only upto 4.x. i want solution for android 5.0 or above.

Comment: @andrucz : is there any other way to set those settings??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi .. since android 5.0 wifiCongiguration class is changed.. You should look android source code and change the code to work in lollypop

Comment: @jackson thanks but  this code is usefull upto 4.x. I am looking  solution for android 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Tested.. Its working in Android 5.1.0, Dont forget to add permissions

```
      WifiConfiguration GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(WifiManager manager)
      {
        if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
            return null;

        List<WifiConfiguration> configurationList = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        WifiConfiguration configuration = null;
        int cur = manager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        for (int i = 0; i < configurationList.size(); ++i)
        {
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = configurationList.get(i);
            if (wifiConfiguration.networkId == cur)
                configuration = wifiConfiguration;
        }

        return configuration;
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void setWifiProxySettings5()
    {
        //get the current wifi configuration
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiConfiguration config = GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(manager);
        if(null == config)
            return;

        try
        {
            //linkProperties is no longer in WifiConfiguration
            Class proxyInfoClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyInfo");
            Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
            setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyInfoClass;
            Class wifiConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
            Method setHttpProxy = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy", setHttpProxyParams);
            setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

            //Method 1 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
            Class ipConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration");
            Field f = ipConfigClass.getField("proxySettings");
            Class proxySettingsClass = f.getType();

            //Method 2 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
            //Note the $ between the class and ENUM
            //Class proxySettingsClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration$ProxySettings");

            Class[] setProxySettingsParams = new Class[1];
            setProxySettingsParams[0] = proxySettingsClass;
            Method setProxySettings = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setProxySettings", setProxySettingsParams);
            setProxySettings.setAccessible(true);


            ProxyInfo pi = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy("127.0.0.1", 8118);
            //Android 5 supports a PAC file
            //ENUM value is "PAC"
            //ProxyInfo pacInfo = ProxyInfo.buildPacProxy(Uri.parse("http://localhost/pac"));

            //pass the new object to setHttpProxy
            Object[] params_SetHttpProxy = new Object[1];
            params_SetHttpProxy[0] = pi;
            setHttpProxy.invoke(config, params_SetHttpProxy);

            //pass the enum to setProxySettings
            Object[] params_setProxySettings = new Object[1];
            params_setProxySettings[0] = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) proxySettingsClass, "STATIC");
            setProxySettings.invoke(config, params_setProxySettings);

            //save the settings
            manager.updateNetwork(config);
            manager.disconnect();
            manager.reconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("wifiProxy", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: not working in my device. it's not updating the fields. I have moto e2 with android 5.0.2.