# Change 3G connection Dns

Tags: android, dns, 3g

I want to change dns when phone using 3g connection.

I know how to change dns when phone using wireless. I learned it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-static-ip-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-android-3-x-or-4?lq=1)

Is there any way to change dns when phone using 3g connection ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting, but it's possible on a rooted device.

I answered a similar question on the [Android Enthusiasts site](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/71624/61821).

If you have a pre-KitKat device, you can find many apps on the Play Store; on a KitKat device there's only one app which I know, and I wrote it. It does basically the same thing, but with the right commands for Android 4.4. You can find the references in the answer I linked.

There's some other app which can do it without root, too, but they create a fake VPN on the same device and redirects all the network traffic through that link... I think they overdo it.