# How to collect network information programmatically

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, gateway, wifimanager

I am trying to collect network information (MAC, IP, DNS 1-2, GateWay, Subnet Mask) programmatically but I am really struggling with DNS 1-2, GateWay, and Subnet Mask. Can you give me a lead on this issue.

With wifimanager I can easly gather IP and MAC address. I can't get others.

```
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo()
            .getIpAddress());
    String mac = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

I also can take all this information from DhcpInfo as below:

```
    DhcpInfo d = wm.getDhcpInfo();
    String DNS1 = d.dns1.toString();
```

but this returns some integer value and I can't parse it into DNS.

Is there any other way to get DNS and gateways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just editted code from selected answer in below question to get needed network information. It's not seems smart but worked for my case.

[How to configue a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi)