# How to set IP Address of a Non-WiFi Enabled Android Device Programmatically? Android 5.x

Tags: android, networking, ip-address

I've looked all over for this and tried my own solutions to no effect.

Basically, I am connecting to another device via ethernet cable (it's kind of hacky, don't worry, I know!). This device cannot utilize wifi, bluetooth, etc. It MUST be via ethernet.

I am able to communicate with this device via this ethernet, but need to change the IP Address to do so.

However, I am only able to find solutions for wifi, which do not work. I'm hoping for a solution that deals more with setting the IP Address for usage with this network.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

NOTE: This is searching for a solution to do this programmatically/via code.

EDIT: For clarification, [this is the attempt with WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599564/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-dns-programmatically-on). There is no WiFi Manager as Wifi is disabled for this Android device (out of necessity). The Reflection is, of course, brittle but seems to be unavoidable.

I began attempting something utilizing the ConnectivityManager and NetworkInterface, but I can't seem to piece together quite how to get to the "setting the IP stage". Mostly this is due to not being able to quite find anything that will allow your to set the IP Address beyond WifiConfiguration (Which, as I mentioned, cannot be used here).

Comment: This is not a programming question.  StackOverflow is not an IT help site.

Comment: Yes, actually it is. I am setting this via code.

Comment: Great, what have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: @JAL I edited the OP to add some more details on this.

Comment: What device are you using? Is this a dev board or something similar (since you have ethernet)? If you have root, you can just use the ifconfig shell command I guess.

Comment: @hna Yup, a dev board. I was hoping to do this without running commands, but it may not be possible to do so.