# How to assign static IP address programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, static-ip-address

I already implemented:

- [How to configure a static IP address, netmask, gateway, DNS programmatically on Android 5.x (Lollipop) for Wi-Fi connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599564/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-dns-programmatically-on)
- [How to configure a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-andro)
- [Set Android IP,DNS,GATEWAY setting programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106502/set-android-ip-dns-gateway-setting-programmatically)

These code samples are compatible until android 5.0. Most of these code samples are now deprecated with respect to new Android versions. If there is any possible solution that works on current Android versions please guide me.

Comment: I am looking same . May I know ,Have you got any solution ?