# Setting IPv6 address for Android WiFi programmaticlly

Tags: android, networking, ip-address, ipv6

Some years ago there was a question about [changing the WiFi IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599564/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-dns-programmatically-on) in Android programmatically. As far as I know there is still no public API for doing this.

Beside this: does anyone have experience with the approach of the linked question and answer with using IPv6 address. When I try this, my whole Android 5.1 crashes. IPv4 addresses are working, though.

Comment: The wifi ip address of which device?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It is an older Motorola Smartphone with Android 5.1. There is only one WiFi interface.