# How to change ipv4 address programmatically on android?

Tags: android, networking, static, ip

I can read ipv4 by this code

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
         String ipaddress = null;
         try {

                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        //if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && !inetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress() && inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress() ) {
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress()) ) {
                             ipaddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
            //    Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
            }

        return ipaddress;
    }
```

But i cant change it.is there any way to change static ip by code?i can only change it on settings configure ethernet device menu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi

Comment: i dont have wifi on my device so i cant use wifi configuration