# Can you set a static IP programmatically for a list of Wifi networks in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, networking, xamarin.android, wifimanager, static-ip-address

I am working on a Xamarin.Android appplication on a tablet device and am working to build an activity that has the capability to connect to any available wifi networks and set separate static IPs for each of them when communicating with the device.

The closest I have come to the solution till now is `Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager.ConnectionInfo.IpAddress` but that is only a getter, and that to the *currently connected* wifi network:

```
public virtual int IpAddress { get; }
```

Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For getting the list of available wifi networks, you can use the [ScanResults Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager.ScanResults/) of [Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager/). For example:

```
var wifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
//open wifi
if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
    wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);
var wifiList = wifiManager.ScanResults;
```

To do this, you will need to enable all wifi related capabilities in your app's manifest like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

To set the static IPs, there is no open API can do this work. And the Apis like `Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiStaticGateway` are obsolete, usually we use reflection in tradition Java android application to set the `WifiConfiguration` like in this case: [How to configue a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi).

Although here in xamarin, the default `WifiConfiguration` is like this:

> {* ID: -1 SSID: null BSSID: null PRIO: 0
>    KeyMgmt: Protocols:
>    AuthAlgorithms:
>    PairwiseCiphers:
>    GroupCiphers:
>    PSK: 
>   IP assignment: UNASSIGNED
>   Proxy settings: UNASSIGNED
>   {LinkAddresses: []  Routes: [] DnsAddresses: [] Domains: nullMTU: 0}
>   }

but after some researching, I found that fields like `ipAssignment` in default Android [WifiConfiguration.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java) are not available in xamarin.android app. We don't know how Xamarin.Android encapsulate its `WifiConfiguration`.

I couldn't find a way to change its `IP assignment` and `Proxy settings`, so I personally doubt setting static IP address can be done unless we know how `WifiConfiguration` of Xamarin.Android looks like.