# Set static IP information in Android device via Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wifi

Is there a way to set IP, Subnet, Gateway, and DNS statically on an Android Device using Android Studio for Android 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not through Android Studio / Android 6.0

Might be possible by contacting the mobile provider, but IMO that's still kind of a long shot

Comment: but i see some codes for lower versions of Android like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi  ......... but it's not working for me , i need something like that to implement it in my Project