# How to assign static ip to ethernet interfact Android

Tags: android, ethernet, static-ip-address

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922455/api-for-configuring-static-ip-addresses-in-an-android-application) which describes how to assign a static ip to a wifi interface. I am currently developing for a Nexus 7 (4.1.2) and have an OTG cable along with a Linksys 300M usb-to-ethernet adapter. Is there a way I could assign a static ip to the ethernet interface?

Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ethernet interface on the device is `eth0`, this should work :

`ifup eth0 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0`

in general

**[`ifup`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifup)**`<interface name> <ip-address> <netmask>`

Comment: ifup is a linux command that I'm guessing will only be available on a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with ifconfig, but changing the IP address manually still requires root or you'll just get an ioctl error informing you as such.