# Set or View "Advanced Wi-fi" Settings programatically

Tags: android-intent, wifi, settings, action, wireless

I need a way to open the "Advanced wifi" settings programatically to let the user change some of the settings, or, preferably, to change these advanced wireless settings programatically.

I can only access the wi-fi settings so far via startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)) but not the advanced settings.

Is there  a way to open the "Advanced wifi" settings?

Comment: I can only access the wi-fi settings so far via startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)) ... but not the advanced settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more settings that might work for you:

From the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) documentation:

- Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS

  ```
  startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
  ```
- Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS

  ```
  startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS));
  ```

Try those two and see if they open what you're after.

Comment: thank you... Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS was what I needed.

Comment: btw, do you know if it is possible to mofify these settings programatically?

Comment: @DanielMF Check out [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7232187/425809)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the code snippet to open WIFI settings page**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity( intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this code to open wifi option directly

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```