# How to programmatically configure IP?

Tags: java, android

I want to configure the IP of an Android device.
Is it possible? If yes, can anybody provide a tutorial for this?
Please support.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not meant for recommending tutorials. Use your google-fu to find the tutorials you're after.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use static IP. Check these threads:

- [How to configue a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-a-static-ip-address-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-androi)
- [API for configuring static IP addresses in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922455/api-for-configuring-static-ip-addresses-in-an-android-application)